# SQL debug - where condition ignored

Tags: mysql, sql

Can somebody explain me this. My SQL:

```
SELECT 
    `offers`.`id`, 
    `offers`.`max_available`, 
    (SELECT COUNT( coupons.id ) FROM coupons WHERE coupons.status = 'Y' AND coupons.offer_id = offers.id) AS coupons_sold
FROM 
    `offers`
WHERE 
    `offers`.`status` IN ('P', 'S') AND 
    `offers`.`published_at` < 1341612000 AND 
    `offers`.`end_at` >1341567914 AND 
    `coupons_sold` < `offers`.`max_available` 
ORDER BY `offers`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0
```

This will return me these 4 rows:

```
id      max_available   coupons_sold
195     19              20
194     9999            0
193     9999            0
159     9999            93
```

How is possible that row with `ID 195` is included, if I have this condition in where `coupons_sold < offers.max_available`? I am clueless!

Comment: Simplified test case throws `Unknown column 'coupons_sold' in 'where clause'` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a1b71/2 Are you sure that nothing else has the `coupons_sold` name too?

Comment: Error using aliases, cannot be used on the where clause http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/problems-with-alias.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query would produce an error, as you can't use in `WHERE` clause, an alias from the `SELECT` list. Unless  table `offers` has a `coupons_sold` column, too!

Try this query, instead:

```
SELECT id, max_available, coupons_sold
FROM
  ( SELECT 
        `offers`.`id`, 
        `offers`.`max_available`, 
        ( SELECT COUNT( coupons.id ) 
          FROM coupons 
          WHERE coupons.status = 'Y' 
            AND coupons.offer_id = offers.id
         ) AS coupons_sold
         offers.created_at
    FROM 
        `offers`
    WHERE 
        `offers`.`status` IN ('P', 'S') AND 
        `offers`.`published_at` < 1341612000 AND 
        `offers`.`end_at` >1341567914
  ) AS tmp
WHERE coupons_sold < max_available 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
  LIMIT 4 OFFSET 0 ;
```

Comment: ... but how `coupons_sold` is visible for the `WHERE` part in OP's original query? It should be visible only for `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`.

Comment: @biziclop: My only guess is that table `offers` has a `coupons_sold` column, too! Otherwise, it would throw an error, as you correctly comemnt.

Comment: The other case would be that the OP is not putting the whole query in the question ...

Comment: yes it's true, coupons_sold is a filed in offers table and I am stupid because I forgot it's there from old version of DB! Not sure how I could miss that! I think this Q can be closed/deleted!